# Unable to boot: Missing Operating system

Tags: boot, grub2, mbr

I had installed Ubuntu 11.10 along with the another Ubuntu 11.10 which already installed on my netbook. Later I formatted the partition I newly installed. Next time when I boot it went to Grub Rescue menu. I boot my system again with Ubuntu USB stick, Then I installed Boot repair package in USB and restored MBR and GRUB menu in the hard disk. Now when I am restarting, I am getting a message "Missing operating system." press any key to continue. 
Can somebody help me on this?

**Below is the output for `sudo fdisk -l`**

```
omitting empty partition (7)

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00058a60

  Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 2048 204072287 102035120 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 204072958 312580095 54253569 5 Extended
/dev/sda5 310507520 312580095 1036288 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6 308432896 310503423 1035264 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 4006 MB, 4006608896 bytes
124 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1017 cylinders, total 7825408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004d3df

  Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdb1 * 62 7818695 3909317 b W95 FAT32
```

**Below is the output for `sudo blkid`**

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/loop1: LABEL="casper-rw" UUID="533defb1-f073-254a-b46f-7ca0ac1f4e0c" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="6a141040-3ba8-457a-9de5-ad06e6057084" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="3a7f62d6-9c65-4d12-a3b6-5d62b9710f7d" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="274da115-cec2-4418-a1af-88fe921e3670" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="PENDRIVE" UUID="EC22-6BE4" TYPE="vfat"
```

**File /boot/grub/grub.cfg**

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
  saved_entry="${chosen}"
  save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6a141040-3ba8-457a-9de5-ad06e6057084
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6a141040-3ba8-457a-9de5-ad06e6057084
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=10
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
if [ ${recordfail} != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
  if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
  if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
  set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
  fi
  else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
  fi
  else
  set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "$linux_gfx_mode" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-12-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6a141040-3ba8-457a-9de5-ad06e6057084
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic root=UUID=6a141040-3ba8-457a-9de5-ad06e6057084 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-12-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6a141040-3ba8-457a-9de5-ad06e6057084
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.0.0-12-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic root=UUID=6a141040-3ba8-457a-9de5-ad06e6057084 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6a141040-3ba8-457a-9de5-ad06e6057084
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6a141040-3ba8-457a-9de5-ad06e6057084
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries. Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment. Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Grub file seems ok. I suggest installing Grub2 manually again. First, start Ubuntu from USB stick and **do not mount** your installed Ubuntu. Open a terminal and apply those commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts  /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install --force /dev/sda
```

You can check if it is OK or not with:

```
grub-install --recheck --force /dev/sda
```

If everything is ok, unmount all the things and quit:

```
exit
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt
sudo reboot
```

Comment: while entering grub-install /dev/sda i am getting following error
<pre> /usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: no signature.
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
</pre>

Comment: Thanks You so much dude. I could do it by a small update to your answer. Thanks again. Appreaciate

Comment: I am glad that it worked. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you remove the USB stick when restarting after you have completed the new install.

Power the laptop down, remove the USB stick then try booting again.

Comment: It is not after new install. I had two ubuntu partitions in it and I deleted one of it. Now unable to boot to the other.