# Installation with USB drive over Joli OS: "Missing Operating System" error

Tags: usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to boot: Missing Operating system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78758/unable-to-boot-missing-operating-system)

I've had success installing and running Ubuntu 11.10 and Lubuntu 11.10 on my Acer Aspire One D255 in the past, but I can no longer use a USB drive (using Universal-USB-Installer-1.8.7.3) to install any version of Ubuntu.

All my prior installs were over either Windows XP or another official Ubuntu version, but now I'm running Joli OS and I can't install Ubuntu anymore. I get a "Missing Operating System" error, and then Joli OS boots.

I have also installed XP on the Acer Aspire One, in an attempt to recreate the conditions which worked last time for installing Ubuntu, however the same problem persists. Is there something wrong with the USB Installer program I am using? Or maybe the ISOs?

Any advice? I have tried the regular installation iso, the alternative. Next is the LTS ISO.

Comment: Your question is similar to [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78758/unable-to-boot-missing-operating-system). More information about your hardware and other details might prove useful. Please edit your question to add that