# USB: Missing Operating System - MAC

Tags: boot, usb, mac

Have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on USB using Live CD. Followed the steps as provided in below link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation

After installation is complete in Refit menu, when i click on Linux icon I receive "Missing Operating System" message. I followed the steps provided in the below link from this forum, but am still receiving the same message.

[Unable to boot: Missing Operating system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78758/unable-to-boot-missing-operating-system)

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use an optical drive if you can.  Otherwise you need to hope one of the answers here works:  http://askubuntu.com/q/10561/43660

Answer (score -1):

you can try this, I've not tried it yet though..
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1908210

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.