# Grub Rescue error after installing windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I've tried using the `ls` command:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (fd0)
```

Then I run `ls` on each one of them and I got the error:

```
Error: Filesystem is unknown
```

But there is one (`fd0`) which takes some time to load and then it shows me this

```
Error: Failure reading sector 0x2 from 'fd0'
```

What can I do? I also have another disk that I unpluged when this happened. I think my Ubuntu was on it. But when I plug it in, I get:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos5) (hd1,msdos1) (fd0)
```

(so 2 more partitions?) again, `ls` on each of them does nothing. I also tried with `set prefix` and `set boot` but nothing happened. Note that if I unplug the main disk (the one with all the (hd0)), the computer doesn't load GRUB. So the Grub is on the HD0 but my Ubuntu I'm pretty sure was on my hd1.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/576631/grub-rescue-after-disk-clone?rq=1 might help, can't say for sure, worth a read

Comment: thanks @SumeetDeshmukh for the answer but it don't do something :/ i don't know why the only partition that work is the FD0 and it tell me the failure reading sector 0x2 from 'fd0'... i might have to use a boot-repair ?  I also need to mention that i don't want to loose all of my files on my drive... i've got ton of info that i need to keep !!! :\  #TrappedInHell -_-

Answer (score 0):

Safest thing to do in this situation would be to:

- [Boot from a live CD or USB Stick](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) ([rufus is a good tool](https://rufus.akeo.ie/))
- [Back-up all data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)
- Format the hard drive
- [Reinstall Windows and Ubuntu both in BIOS mode or UEFI mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) (One or the other)
- Restore all data

Comment: How can i save all my data then format the drive ? i don't have a CD of my Windows... (Note that all my data are on the Windows side...) If i create a USB with like windows 7 on it or windows 10 (the installer) can i see my folder then copy them and erase all the drive ? (i have 2 drives)

Comment: make a bootable ubuntu live USB, connect it, boot from it and select "try ubuntu without installing" and take backup. file system aren't accessible from windows installer as per my knowledge, appropriate links are given in the answer . feel free to ask anything else. (note that it's the safest and easiest way if you keep added more details and what you tried in you question more experienced users  might have an answer for you without reinstalling operating systems)

Comment: i would delete everything if i could... the thing is, i really need the folder (music, videos, software, etc..) that are on my windows, side... is there ANY way to see these folder on the drive ? like a /home folder or the /ProgramsFiles foler ? like can i explore the /user/<name>/desktop and then copy everything on a external drive ? I ONLY NEED THAT... if i can find a way to copy that, i copy them and then BYE BYE old windows and old ubuntu...

Comment: @alexischalut97 you can see the NTFS partition from live Ubuntu, so that wouldn't be the problem, it's inside c/user/folders i think

Comment: you can accept the answer by clicking on tick mark, if it was helpful to you, so that other people know if this question is solved

Comment: Yep just saw that... thanks everyone, i was able with the Boot-Repair to access my windows folder (like user and programs files...) _THANKS ! :)_

Comment: @alexischalut97 welcome

Comment: Now... how do i uninstall both operating systems ? Ubuntu and Windows ? Can i make it by the Boot-Repair i just made ???

Comment: just make a bootable USB drive or CD for Windows and Install Windows (where windows initially was) by formatting the partition. then make Bootable USB drive for Ubuntu and install where that was by formatting that partition. for easy recovery of data you should consider making a different `/home` partition just in case

Comment: if you've backed up everything on the drive, it'd be good to make new partition table altogether

Comment: So basically, i just need to format all the partition i have ? Then i just ré-install ?

Comment: There is no need to format all the partitions (for example, partition with music, photos or movies), just the ones with OS on them. but if you can do it, then it would be good. A fresh start. i've updated the answer with a tool to create live USB from any windows PC

Comment: yeah i was thinking about a fresh start right after i backup my data...

Comment: make sure to edit the answer with the steps that worked for you. and accept it so that other users know that it's solved @alexischalut97